# Python: Need to write multiple records onto an excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write multiple lines to an excel sheet using python. When i try to print the "record" below it gives multiple lines. Please let me know how to write all the lines to an excel file. The following code writes just 1 line.

```
for row in table.findAll('tr', { "class" : "product-row" }):
    col = row.findAll('td')
    #print(col[0].a.img['src'])
    #print(col)

    Image = col[0].a.img['src']
    Name = col[1].a.text
    Width = col[3].text

    record = (Image,Name,Width)

    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

    for col_index, item in enumerate(record):
        sheet1.write(i, col_index, item)

    book.save("trial1.xls")
    #print(record)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be from the lines where `book` and `sheet1` are defined, if you move these outside of the entire for loop and move the `book.save` outside of the end, it should print all of the entries.

```
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

i = 0 # define a row counter

for row in table.findAll('tr', { "class" : "product-row" }):
    col = row.findAll('td')

    Image = col[0].a.img['src']
    Name = col[1].a.text
    Width = col[3].text

    record = (Image,Name,Width)

    for col_index, item in enumerate(record):
        sheet1.write(i, col_index, item)
    i += 1 # <-- increment the row counter

book.save("trial1.xls")
```

**PRE-EDIT:**

From the code provided, depending on the indentation levels it could be one of a few issues.

1. you are looping over the sheet creation so it overwrites each time, this can be fixed by defining the workbook and sheet before beginning the for loop.
2. the record variable is re-defined every time through the loop, this would only store 1 line at a time, either the first (if the entire block is within the for loop) or last line (see next point).
3. of `col = row.findAll('td')` is the only line in the for loop, it is being overwritten, only storing the final line when it goes to print to the xls file.

`i` is not defined in the code shown above for `sheet.write(i, col_index, item)`, more of a note than an error.

If you update the indentation in the code I could provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: thanks! Sorry for the confusion. I updated the code. Please check. I oberve that even i create the excel in the beginning the record is being over written. How to define the "record" and pass each row to it to write. Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: posted a new question. Please have a look if you can. Thanks